# The letters in the set {a, e, i, o, u, A, E, I, O, U} are considered vocal. for the word "caracter" will be displayed on the screen: "caparapacteper"

Tags: c

Read the taste formed by a word of up to 100 characters, small and large letters of the alphabet. The program determines the transformation of the read word by replacing each vowel of the word formed - a string consisting of three characters namely: that vowel followed by letters and then, there is not yet a respective vowel, as in the example given below. The program displays the word obtained on the screen. The letters in the set {a, e, i, o, u, A, E, I, O, U} are considered as vowels.

i think that i missed something cuz the program gives me nothing on output:
[image]

Program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main() {
    char s[100], voc[10], aux[100];
    strcpy(voc,"aeiouAEIOU");
    scanf("%s",&s[100]);

    for(int i=0;i<strlen(s);i++)
        if(strchr(voc,s[i])) {
            strcpy(aux,s+i+1);
                s[i+1]='p';
                s[i+2]=s[i];
                strcpy(s+i+3,aux);
                 i+=2; 
        }

    printf("%s",s);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `voc` does not have enough space for the `'\0'` terminator.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&s[100]);` ==> `scanf("%99s", s);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several prolems in your code

> ```
> char s[100], voc[10], aux[100];
>
> strcpy(voc,"aeiouAEIOU");
> ```

you need to size *voc* 11 to have place for the final null character

or must better just use

```
const char * voc = "aeiouAEIOU";
```

in

> scanf("%s",&s[100]);

you ask *scanf* to write out of *s*, you wanted

```
scanf("%s",&s[0]);
```

which is equivalent to

```
scanf("%s",s);
```

anyway *scan* can write out of *s* if the input is too long, so do :

```
scanf("%99s",s);
```

In

> ```
>   s[i+1]='p';
>   s[i+2]=s[i];
>   strcpy(s+i+3,aux);
> ```

you can write out of *s*, the behavior is undefined

Comment: Notice: Although `const char * voc` is valid, it looks like a multiplicative expression. I suggest you prefer `const char* voc` or `const char *voc`, which is less confusing.